# Webservice creation in Drupal 6.22

Tags: drupal-6

I am new to Drupal. The project on which i am working is in Drupal and its version is 6.22. Please tell me is there any module to create webservices in Drupal 6.22? How to create webservices and how to execute services in Drupal 6.22?

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is no link for downloadin services module for drupal 6 on drupal.org. Do you know how to use drush ? If yes, then just type

> drush dl services

This should download appropriate version of services module for your drupal 6 . You should also install **rest server** module and configure both appropriately for you requirements. I will help you if you are able to install these modules and explain your requirements to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have enabled the Rest server module. Can you please let me know, how to use this module to create webservices?

Comment: Did you also enable the services module ? The rest server only allows control over the way data is available for services module. It is the services module that actually open the way for usage of your website over web services. I hope you are getting my point. If you have enabled the services module then define the end-point for the exposed services and then we can configure the Rest Server module

Comment: I have enabled the services module also and follow the process to create webservice by creating endpoint but it was not working at all. But there is one more problem, if you search on internet for drupal 6.22 version service module is not available. May be this is the reason that service module is not working. If this is the reason then please let me know the alternate solution for this.

Comment: what is the version of services module that you have installed ?